# Failed to resolve: com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, pdf-viewer

I am trying use this library in my Project. But i am unable to download it by adding it in gradle build. In fact i am even unable to download any library through gradle. I need to manually download a jar file and add that as a library. But in this case I couldn't find the jar file for PDFviewer.

**Build.gradle (Module)**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.9.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
compile files('libs/asmack.jar')
compile files('libs/android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar')
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1'  //unable to add this.
}
```

**Build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
   // google()  
   // mavenLocal() // tried everything
}
}
```

I have tried almost everything for the past three days given in SO but still couldn't find any solution to this. It will be helpful even if i get the jar file.

Comment: Can you give the logs ?

Comment: By the way `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` *already compiles* all the JAR files in the libs

Comment: But i am unable to get this particular library. @cricket_007

Comment: I know. Just pointing out `compile files('libs/*.jar')` is not necessary

Comment: @RakeshPolo use latest `compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.3'`

Comment: hey @IntelliJAmiya your answer worked. I just made a casual error. pasted like this in a hurry ` maven { maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" } }`  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add

```
repositories 
   {
      maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
   }
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Error:You must specify a URL for a Maven repository.` My AS version is 2.2.3

Comment: `jcenter()` is the same, no?

Comment: It Worked! @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: add https worked, `maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }`

Answer (score 23):

Simply add this line into the **build.gradle(app level)**

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

If you have **android studio bumblebee** or **android studio arctic fox** then,

add **gradlePluginPortal()** into **settings.gradle** file

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it's a problem with jCenter (deprecated) when he's drop.

add :

```
allprojects {repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this line into the build.gradle(app level)

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

If you have android studio bumblebee or android studio arctic fox then,

add gradlePluginPortal() into settings.gradle file

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

also add

```
android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure adding this to your allprojects repositories like this inside android\build.gradle file: do not forget that it should be SSL secured using https://

```
repositories
   {
     maven {
        url ("https://jcenter.bintray.com")
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the maven URL and GitHub dependencies...

You might turn on your internet connection for Gradle to download necessary dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

Delete any of other jcenter definitions under repositories

```
jcenter()
```

or

```
jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
```

and than put this line under repositories part

```
maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In my case, it's working with the beta version 
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'

 I added all the things they telling:

repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
And added this to gradle.properties on Gradle Scripts because I was having problems with duplicated classes -->
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

### N.B: My android version:
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4

### Q: Problem: my app does not support `PDFView`

### A: Solution:

Step-1: I added library's beta version inside `dependencies {}` of `build.gradle(app)`  given below:

```
dependencies {

    implementation ("com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1")
    
}
```

Step-2: I added  `gradlePluginPortal()` insise `repositories{}`,like given below:

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
```

Step-3:And added `android.enableJetifier=true` to gradle.properties on Gradle Scripts, because I was having problems with duplicated classes